# ThreeJS / FBXLoader / Set new path for Textures

Tags: three.js

Can i set a New path for All Textures, with FBXLoader ?

by default, textures should be located beside the FBX model file.

i want to place all textures in a different folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with [Loader.setResourcePath](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/Loader.setResourcePath):

```
const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
loader.setResourcePath( 'path/to/my/textures/' );
```

`three.js R108`